# How to compare array elements in BASH?

Tags: arrays, bash, syntax

I've got an array `a` and `b`, and I need the correct `bash` syntax to compare array elements in this for loop:

```
for ((x=0;x<10;x++)); do
    if [ "$a[$x+1]" -gt "$a[$x]" ]; then
        $b[x+1]=1
    if [ "$a[$x+1]" -lt "$a[$x]" ]; then 
        $b[x+1]=0
    fi
```

How do I get `bash` to correctly assign a value of 1 to array element `b[x+1]` when the array element `a[x+1]` is greater than `a[x]`?

So if array element `a[1]` is greater than `a[0]`, then `b[1]=1`?

An easier way to ask this question, and that would be more simple, would be:

How do I have it know if array element 1 is greater than 0?

```
 if [ "$a[1]" -gt "$a[0]" ]; 
 then
 echo element 1  greater than element 0
 fi
```

The above code gives UNEXPECTED END OF FILE, as if I'm missing some syntax. Anyone know this BASH syntax?

UPDATE:
So this is the script file:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 declare -a a
 declare -a b
 readarray a < arraydatafile 

 for ((x=0;x<5;x++)); 
 do
 if [ "${a[$x+1]}" -gt "${a[$x]}" ]; 
 then  
 b[x+1]=1   
 fi
 done
```

arraydatafile:

```
 1
 2
 1
 4
 5
 4
 2
 8
```

root@debian:/home/l0l/Documents/# bash script

script line 8: [: 2
: integer expression expected
script: line 8: [: 1
: integer expression expected
script: line 8: [: 4
: integer expression expected
script: line 8: [: 5
: integer expression expected
script: line 8: [: 4
: integer expression expected

Anyone know the exact syntax?

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. There is no `'$'` before **assignments** and you access values in arrays with, e.g. `${a[$((x+1))]}` or where no addition on the index takes place `${a[$x]}` (or for indexed array `${a[x]}`)

Comment: I suggest to add a `done` and a `fi`.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest this syntax:

```
if [ "${a[$x+1]}" -gt "${a[$x]}" ]; then  # with { and }
  b[x+1]=1                                # without $
```

Comment: While bash lets you get away with it, I always use the *arithmetic operator* when additions are made. For indexed arrays bash also allows `${a[x]}`

Comment: This does not work when trying to read only. `echo b[x]` works, but `echo b[x+1]` does not. How can I do that?

Comment: @MoteZart: If you use `bash` this should work: `b=(x y z); echo "${b[x]} ${b[x+1]}"`

Answer (score -1):

In bash the `lt` or `gt` conditionals require an integer value. If the contents of `arraydatafile` doesn't contain strictly integers you will receive the errors you are dealing with.

You should use the following to push `arraydatafile` into an array;

`declare -a a;
a=($(cat arraydatafile))`

When dealing with comparisons of arrays you can use of the `comm` binary.

For example:

`$(comm -13 <(printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"|sort -u) <(printf '%s\n' "${b[@]}"|sort -u)))`

That snippit will compare arrays `a` & `b` and provide an intersection of the two. For more information about the use of `comm` see the man pages; i.e. `man comm`.

Comment: `b[[$((x+1))]=1` ?? and aren't array elements accessed with, e.g. `${a[$((x+1))]}` ?

Comment: The array index is an arithmetic context so you can simply use `${a[x+1]}`